# adicionar no firebase com angularfire $add

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Meus scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.2.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.6.6/firebase.js"></script>
```

Olá sou iniciante com firebase e angular, tenho a seguinte situação no meu banco:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs. valores inseridos manualmente.

Agora gostaria de deixar dinâmico com angular, e estou fazendo seguinte forma o controller:

```
   app.controller("CtrlList", function($scope, $firebaseArray){

    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("users");

    $scope.addUser = function(){
      $scope.users.$add({
        text: $scope.newUserText
      });
    };
```

E meu fomulário assim:

```
<form ng-submit="addUser()">
  <input ng-model="newUserText" />
  <button type="submit">Add User</button>
</form>
```

Por ser iniciante estou um pouco perdido e não consigo salvar no firebase, acredito que me falta algum conceito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deixo registrado a resolução do meu problema, assim o `controller` ficou da seguinte forma:

```
app.controller("CtrlList", function($scope, $firebaseArray){

    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("users");

    data = $scope.users = $firebaseArray(ref);

    $scope.addUser = function(){          
      writeUserData($scope.newUserId, $scope.newUserName);          
    };

    function writeUserData(userId, name) {
      firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
        name: name
      });
    }

  });
```

E o `form` assim:

```
<form ng-submit="addUser()">
  <input ng-model="newUserId" placeholder="User" />
  <input ng-model="newUserName" placeholder="Name" />
  <button type="submit">Add User</button>
</form>
```